# Difference between using NULL and CGAffineTransformIdenity for transform argument in a path

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-graphics, quartz-2d, core-foundation

Is there any difference especially with regards to performance between the following:

**Approach 1 - use NULL transform:**

```
- (CGPathRef)createPathForRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, rect.size.width / 2, rect.size.height - 1);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, (rect.size.width / 2) - 20, rect.size.height - 22);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0, rect.size.height - 22);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, rect.size.width - 1, 0);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, rect.size.width - 1, rect.size.height - 22);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, (rect.size.width / 2) + 20, rect.size.height - 22);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
    return path;
}
```

**Approach 2 - use Identity transform:**

```
- (CGPathRef)createPathForRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, &transform, rect.size.width / 2, rect.size.height - 1);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, &transform, (rect.size.width / 2) - 20, rect.size.height - 22);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, &transform, 0, rect.size.height - 22);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, &transform, 0, 0);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, &transform, rect.size.width - 1, 0);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, &transform, rect.size.width - 1, rect.size.height - 22);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, &transform, (rect.size.width / 2) + 20, rect.size.height - 22);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
    return path;
}
```

I'm guessing that they're exactly the same, but wanted to confirm this.

Comment: Did you measure it? Instruments can probably give you some idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the docs for a function such as `CGPathMoveToPoint`, it says this:

> *m*
>   A pointer to an affine transformation matrix, or NULL if no transformation is needed. If specified, Quartz applies the transformation to the point before changing the path.

Since `CGAffineTransformIdentity` is essentially no transform as it is the **identity**, then it follows that these two pieces of code are, in fact, the same.

Comment: The effect is the same, but it sounds as though Quartz will do extra work if you specify even just an identity transform. This is what I wanted to confirm (I know - it's a trivial question, but curiosity kills that cat ;) )